# Incorrect Execution Time in Linux

Tags: c, linux

To the guys whom marked my question as answered/duplicate: Those solutions in the given link cannot calculate the CPU time in a multi-thread program in Linux.

I am using the following code to find the execution time of my code. It works perfectly on my Windows 10 machine but when it comes to Linux, I get incorrect execution time (for example the real execution time is less than 2 seconds but the code prints 10 seconds). I have tried both GCC and Intel compilers but still have the same issue. Any idea what is wrong? Thank you for your time and help.

```
clock_t begin;
clock_t end;
double time_spent;

begin = clock();
// run some calculations //
end = clock();
time_spent = ((double)(end - begin)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Elapsed: %.12f \n\n", time_spent);
```

Comment: What does the Linux [`time` command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utime.htm) give you if you try it on the raw program?

Comment: Please provide some [MCVE] in your question. Which is also missing the `linux` tag

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully the `man` pages of [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) and of [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) (and perhaps also of [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), which probably is used to implement `clock`). The `clock` documentation explains:

> The `clock()` function returns an *approximation* of **processor time** used
>          by the program.

<sup>(emphasis is mine)</sup>

Use also [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) to measure the time of your program.

Notice that `clock` function is measuring the *CPU* time, not the real wall-clock time.

It is actually rumored that [on Windows, `clock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx) is *incorrectly* measuring the real wall-clock time. But the [standard `clock` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock) should indeed give processor time (check [n1570](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html), the C11 standard, §7.27.2.1 for more).

For example, if your long-going calculation is doing some I/O (and that is often the case), it might wait for the disk (or for output to the terminal emulator, or input from the user), and then the CPU time and the real wall-clock time are very different.

> I get incorrect execution time (for example the real execution time is less than 2 seconds but the code prints 10 seconds).

If your program is multi-threaded, it might have a processor time (accumulated on several cores) which is bigger than the real wall-clock time.

> I have tried both GCC and Intel compilers but still have the same issue.

The `clock` function is provided by your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library). The standard `<time.h>` header is just *declaring* it.  Your `libc.so.6`, probably from [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (but you might also try [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)), is *implementing* it. So you should expect that changing compilers won't change the behavior of `clock`.

> Any idea what is wrong?

Perhaps your expectations are wrong (but without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we cannot be sure).

You comment also:

> I was not able to find a simple way to get CPU time in my program.

Consider then using [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with one of

```
   CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID (since Linux 2.6.12)
          Per-process CPU-time clock (measures CPU time consumed by all
          threads in the process).

   CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID (since Linux 2.6.12)
          Thread-specific CPU-time clock.
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. My program is multi-threaded (OpenMP) as you mentioned in your comment. It seems I need to use another timing function.

Comment: Not necessarily. You may need to *interpret* the timing figures differently.

Comment: I tried clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &var) and it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: That measures real wall clock time, not CPU time

Comment: I was not able to find a simple way to get CPU time in my program.